# Does Beanstalkd support transient messages?

Tags: message-queue, ttl, beanstalkd

I would like to know if beanstalkd, the message-queue, supports transient message.
A message put by a beanstalkc needs to have TTL (say few seconds) where if no-one reserves (fetches) that message then it should get auto-deleted from the queue.
Does it support TTL? I found TTR (Time-To-Run) but that is different and associated with the JOB run time mgmt.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to do an explicit delete (either when it is reserved or buried)

Refer: https://github.com/beanstalkd/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L82